# google trends readlines with r

Tags: r, curl, rcurl, google-trends

I have a simple URL 
http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=amazon&date=today%203-m&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3

putting this into `readLines` gives me an error

```
readLines("http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=amazon&date=today%203-m&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3")

Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '203 Non-Authoritative Information'
```

I'm sure I have to use something like RCurl and log into google (like suggested in other posts). But my question is, why my approach doesn't work? I tried this url in several browsers without logging in, but using it with R doesn't work. can anyone give me some pointers?

**EDIT**

I think the problem is because my IP or something got blocked. I tried it on several computers and the results were always the same: It worked 3 or 4 times in R and than it didn't and still doesn't. Nevertheless it works in the browser.

Comment: Works for me. Can you access any other web sites via `readLines`? Maybe its a local network HTTP proxy requirement? Have you tried it from home and work networks?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to try a different approach to read in a website you can use the XML library.
For example,

```
library(XML)
url <-"http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=amazon&date=today%203 m&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3"

htmlParse(url)
```

gave me the desired output.